# How to float table to top of pages

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6.1in, 9in}]{geometry}
\onecolumn
\title{Computation of Orbital Elements Method of Gauss}
\author{Team 2}
\date{\\*[1ex] {\textit{21 July 2019}}}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
The determination of asteroids' orbits helps us in identifying Potentially Hazardous Asteroids (PHAs) 
\\* [1ex]\textbf{Key words:} Asteroids, 2002 GG5, Method of Gauss, Orbit Determination
\end{abstract}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\newpage
\twocolumn
\setlength{\columnsep}{20mm} %column separation
\setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr (3in -1in/16)*2 + 3in/8}
\footskip = 5 cm

\section{Introduction}
His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]

\begin{tabular}[t]
{ c c c c }
\cline(1)



 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Calculated Orbital Elements} \\
 \hline
Element&L& W &K\\
 \hline

 a [AU]&2.235230   & 2.339165   &2.249526  \\ 
  e&0.277364&   0.321138  & 0.283313 \\
  i [Deg]&2.332732 &2.320495 & 2.329050\\
 $\Omega$ [Deg]&187.313727    &182.103229 & 186.510890\\
 $\omega$ [Deg]& 97.033028&   114.173368 & 99.913125\\
 M [Deg]&351.551516& 346.410309  & 350.539311   \\


\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \begin{tabular}[t]
{ c{1.7cm}c{3cm}c{3cm}c{3cm} }
\cline(1)



 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Calculated Orbital Elements} \\
 \hline
Element&Li& Wu &Kraus\\
 \hline

 a [AU]&2.235230   & 2.339165   &2.249526  \\ 
  e&0.277364&   0.321138  & 0.283313 \\
  i [Deg]&2.332732 &2.320495 & 2.329050\\
 $\Omega$ [Deg]&187.313727    &182.103229 & 186.510890\\
 $\omega$ [Deg]& 97.033028&   114.173368 & 99.913125\\
 M [Deg]&351.551516& 346.410309  & 350.539311   \\


\end{tabular}

Answer (score 3):

- `\begin{table}[t]...\end{table}` is missing around your tabular, that means that top is the only allowed option or `\begin{table*}....\end{table*}` if the table should span both columns
- `\maketitle` ought to be inside the document
- abstract also needs to be inside the document
- you must remove `\\*[1ex]` from within `\date{}`

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6.1in, 9in}]{geometry}
\onecolumn
\title{Computation of Orbital Elements Method of Gauss}
\author{Team 2}
\date{{\textit{21 July 2019}}}




%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The determination of asteroids' orbits helps us in identifying Potentially Hazardous Asteroids (PHAs) 
\\* [1ex]\textbf{Key words:} Asteroids, 2002 GG5, Method of Gauss, Orbit Determination
\end{abstract}

\newpage
\twocolumn
\setlength{\columnsep}{20mm} %column separation
\setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr (3in -1in/16)*2 + 3in/8}
\footskip = 5 cm

\section{Introduction}
His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
%\cline(1)
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Calculated Orbital Elements} \\
 \hline
Element&L& W &K\\
 \hline
 a [AU]&2.235230   & 2.339165   &2.249526  \\ 
  e&0.277364&   0.321138  & 0.283313 \\
  i [Deg]&2.332732 &2.320495 & 2.329050\\
 $\Omega$ [Deg]&187.313727    &182.103229 & 186.510890\\
 $\omega$ [Deg]& 97.033028&   114.173368 & 99.913125\\
 M [Deg]&351.551516& 346.410309  & 350.539311   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \subsection{Orbital Elements}

\begin{tabular}[t]{ c c c c }
\cline(1)

Comment: I did this but it's still in the middle of the column?

Comment: @user193157 Please show complete code to reproduce

Comment: \begin{tabular}[t]
{ c c c c }
\cline(1)



 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Calculated Orbital Elements} \\
 \hline
Element&Li& Wu &Kraus\\
 \hline

 a [AU]&2.235230   & 2.339165   &2.249526  \\ 
  e&0.277364&   0.321138  & 0.283313 \\
  i [Deg]&2.332732 &2.320495 & 2.329050\\
 $\Omega$ [Deg]&187.313727    &182.103229 & 186.510890\\
 $\omega$ [Deg]& 97.033028&   114.173368 & 99.913125\\
 M [Deg]&351.551516& 346.410309  & 350.539311   \\


\end{tabular}

Comment: @user193157 A complete document that compiles

Comment: how do I send it to you just copy paste?

Comment: @user193157 use this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/500780/edit and copy and paste it there

Comment: ok now it's at the top of the column is there a way to make it take up the whole width of two columns

Comment: @user193157 for two columns: `\begin{table*}....\end{table*}`

Comment: that put it in the middle of the first column on a blank page?

Comment: I figured it out thank u so much

Comment: how do I turn section headers into roman numerals

Answer (score 3):

If you want the tabular material to "float" to the top of column, you must encase it in a "floating object", such as a `table` environment. To make sure it gets placed at the top of a column, you need the placement specifier `[t!]`, i.e., you need to write `\begin{table}[t!]`.

Incidentally, unless you have somehow modified the `c` column type to start taking an argument, I don't believe that `c{1.7cm}c{3cm}c{3cm}c{3cm}` can compile successfully. I would use an ordinary `c` column type instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6.1in, 9in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3] % filler text

\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Calculated Orbital Elements}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{} lccc @{}}
\hline
 Element & Li & Wu & Kraus\\
\hline

 a [AU]        &2.235230   & 2.339165   &2.249526  \\ 
 e             &0.277364&   0.321138  & 0.283313 \\
 i [Deg]       &2.332732 &2.320495 & 2.329050\\
 $\Omega$ [Deg]&187.313727    &182.103229 & 186.510890\\
 $\omega$ [Deg]& 97.033028&   114.173368 & 99.913125\\
 M [Deg]       &351.551516& 346.410309  & 350.539311   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4-10] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: how do I turn section headers into roman numerals

Comment: @user193157 - Specify `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}` in the preamble. If you want lowercase roman numerals, use `\roman` instead of `\Roman`.

Comment: ok so now I have II.4 how do I make the sub into a roman numeral

Comment: @user193157 - Sorry, but your follow-up questions do not appear to be related to the main topic of your query. If you have questions about how to display the numbers of various levels of sectioning commands using Roman numerals, you should ask a new query.