# how to float to top of column and keep under text

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {pics/} }
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6.1in, 9in}]{geometry}
\onecolumn
\title{Computation of Orbital Elements Method of Gauss}
\author{Team 2}
\date{\\*[1ex] {\textit{21 July 2019}}}



\begin{abstract}
The determination of asteroids' orbits helps us in identifying Potentially Hazardous Asteroids (PHAs) 
\\* [1ex]\textbf{Key words:} Asteroids, 2002 GG5, Method of Gauss, Orbit Determination
\end{abstract}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\twocolumn
\setlength{\columnsep}{20mm} %column separation
\setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr (3in -1in/16)*2 + 3in/8}
\footskip = 5 cm

\section{Introduction}
His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the right to import National Panasonic's parts to make radios throughout Nepal.[8]
\begin{table*}[t]
\onecolumn\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]
{ c c c c }
\cline(1)



 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Calculated Orbital Elements} \\
 \hline
Element&L& W &K\\
 \hline

 a [AU]&2.235230   & 2.339165   &2.249526  \\ 
  e&0.277364&   0.321138  & 0.283313 \\
  i [Deg]&2.332732 &2.320495 & 2.329050\\
 $\Omega$ [Deg]&187.313727    &182.103229 & 186.510890\\
 $\omega$ [Deg]& 97.033028&   114.173368 & 99.913125\\
 M [Deg]&351.551516& 346.410309  & 350.539311   \\


\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\twocolumn
\section{Introduction}
His grandfather, Bhuramal Das Chaudhary, migrated to Nepal from Rajasthan in the 19th century. After his arrival at the age of 20 he started a textile business in the 1930s.[8] A few years later, after the 1934 Nepal–Bihar earthquake, he became the first in Nepal to start a formally registered clothing company.[8] His father, Lunkaran Das Chaudhary, continued to develop the textile business, and also established international-trading houses, and a construction company.[8] In 1968 Lunkaran Das Chaudhary founded Arun Emporium, a retail store which was his most successful enterprise.[8] At the age of eighteen, Binod Chaudhary was about to head towards India to study chartered accountancy however his father was diagnosed with heart disease, the doctor told him his father could not continue to run the family business.[13] As he was the eldest son in the family he stepped into the family business.[13] He told The Telegraph, "My life was overnight changed completely. I did not have a choice at all. But it has made me a tougher man."[13] He also stated "I would have liked to study further but I was required to do my duty" In an interview with Hong Kong Tatler.[14]

He considered importing Japanese Suzuki cars to Nepal. He says, "Suzuki did not trust me as I was a young clothes trader. I convinced them. They gave me a trial dealership along with four others to sell Suzuki in Nepal. Whoever sold most cars in six months would get the dealership."[15]

His first independent business was in 1973, it was a discothèque company called Copper Floor.[8] The company was a huge success, because of the many wealthy and powerful people who visited the club.[8] In 1979 Chaudhary made a deal with Japanese electronic firm National Panasonic, which was his first multinational deal.[8] The deal gave him the rig
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable. Currently it yields error messages regarding the `abstract` environment, the use of `\\*[1ex]` in `\date`and the use of `\cline(1)`. Also, how is your question related to `tabularx` (the tag you uesd) as you don't load the `tabularx` package?

Comment: Could you please also extend your description of the desired output? (Probably with a sketch?)

Comment: Please also explain the connection or differences to your previous question [How to float table to top of pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500780/134144)